# how to add value of input textfield that is next to an element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dynamic form that is generated by php.

```
  print '<div class="choices">';
    print '<input type="radio" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="1"/>' . $row['answer1'] .'<br/>';
    print '<input type="hidden" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="1"/>';

    print '<input type="radio" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="2"/>' . $row['answer2'] .'<br/>';
    print '<input type="hidden" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="1"/>';

    print '<input type="radio" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="3"/>' . $row['answer3'] .'<br/>';
    print '<input type="hidden" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="1"/>';

    print '<input type="radio" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="4"/>' . $row['answer4'] .'<br/>';
    print '<input type="hidden" class="answer' . $q . '" id="answer'. $q . '" name="answer'. $q . '"value="1"/>';

    print '<input type="hidden" class="your" id="answer" name="correctanswer'. $q . '" value="0"/>';

    print '</div>';
```

I want to change the value of input type hidden which has a class of `your` that is next to div `.choices`. I used the jQuery below.

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
//  alert(this.value);
    $(".choices ~ .answer").val(this.value);

});
```

But it is not working. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

HTML

Comment: I don't know what definition of "next to" you're using that would place the `.your` element next to the `.choices` element. They're not text to each other at all. The `.your` is a child of `.choices`, and in this case is the last child. However, the `.your` is a *sibling*` of the element clicked, so `$(this).nextAll(".your")` or `$(this).nextUntil(".your").next()`.

Comment: try `$(this).next().val(this.value);`

Comment: yeah..it will work but how about if you have 5 sets of that HTML code.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: And why are you using `.answer` to reach an element with the class `your`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have the same ID on multiple elements. IDs should be unique. I'm unclear as to where input.your is located, your description says it's a sibling of div.choices, but the code indicates it's a child of div.choices...

If input.your is a sibling of div.choices:

```
    $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings('.your').val($(this).val());
    });
```

If input.your is a child of div.choices:

```
    $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
        $(this).siblings('.your').val($(this).val());
    });
```

EDIT: misunderstood question

Comment: none of the `radio` elements are will reach the targeted element with the class `your` using `.next()`.

Comment: Edited the answer. Didn't realize the hidden input .your was a sibling of div.choices. Actually... looking at the OP, it's a child of div.choices...?